# python feature extraction: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, feature-extraction

if am writing this ::

```
bow_vect = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=2, max_features=1000, stop_words='english')
bow = bow_vect.fit_transform(combi['tidy_tweet'])
```

i am getting this error ::

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-745529b5930e> in <module>
      1 bow_vect = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=2, max_features=1000, stop_words='english')
----> 2 bow = bow_vect.fit_transform(combi['tidy_tweet'])

c:\users\avinash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1010 
   1011         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1012                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1013 
   1014         if self.binary:

c:\users\avinash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    920         for doc in raw_documents:
    921             feature_counter = {}
--> 922             for feature in analyze(doc):
    923                 try:
    924                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

c:\users\avinash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    306                                                tokenize)
    307             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 308                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    309 
    310         else:

c:\users\avinash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(x)
    254 
    255         if self.lowercase:
--> 256             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    257         else:
    258             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What happens if you do `print(combi['tidy_tweet'])`

Comment: it is printing the tokenized tweet

Comment: 0        [when, father, dysfunct, selfish, drag, kid, i...
1        [thank, #lyft, credit, caus, they, offer, whee...
2                                  [bihday, your, majesti]
3                         [#model, love, take, with, time]
4                             [factsguid, societi, #motiv]
5        [huge, fare, talk, befor, they, leav, chao, di...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the type of `combi['tidy_tweet']` actually is this is likely because fit_transform expects an iterable of strings and you're supplying it a Series.

`combi['tidy_tweet']` should actually be a list of strings for fit_transform to work. Currently it looks like it is a Series of a list of strings.

So your best bet is to concatenate the tokens within each row (list) into one string, package these strings into one list and then use fit_transform on it.

Comment: thank you @Robs got you now. now it is up and running